# How to split data from different applications into their own indices?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I'm trying to split logs from different applications into their respective indices. Here is what I'm trying:

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - "/opt/logs/filebeat_test_1.log"
  fields:
    application: "APP_TEST_1"
    type: "logs1"
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - "/opt/logs/filebeat_test_2.log"
  fields:
    application: "APP_TEST_2"
    type: "logs2"

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
}

output {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts => "es-ingest:9200"
        index => "%{[fields.application]}-%{[beat.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

However, I'm not getting the expected indices. Is this correct way to split different logs from different applications into their respective indices? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fine approach if you want to send different files to different indices.
Try this syntax on the output of Logstash:

```
index => "%{[fields][application]}"
```